# Creating paypal billing agreement using stored card information (vault)

Tags: java, paypal, paypal-rest-sdk

I am successful in creating PayPal `billing agreements` using `credit_card` as a payment option by providing credit card details (i.e credit card number, expiry dates, etc).

But the problem comes when I tried to use a stored card (card token) to create agreement. I tried to set `CreditCardToken` object in `fundingInstrument`

```
String creditCardId = customerCreditCardRepo.findOneByCustomerIdAndDefaultCard(customerId, 1).getCardId();
CreditCardToken creditCardToken = new CreditCardToken();
creditCardToken.setCreditCardId(creditCardId);
fundingInstrument.setCreditCardToken(creditCardToken);
```

But I get the following error:

```
response-code: 400  details: name: VALIDATION_ERROR message: Invalid request - see details  details: [ErrorDetails(field=payer, issue=Funding Instrument Details are missing or Funding instrument not supported. Only credit-card is supported., purchaseUnitReferenceId=null, code=null)] debug-id: 2d6eff7aa27e3 information-link: https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/docs/api/#VALIDATION_ERROR
```

It clearly states that only `Only credit-card is supported`. Is there any way that I can retrieve the card number any way without the need for the customer to enter the card number.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Billing agreements no longer support the Vaulted credit cards. They require that a credit card be submitted with the API call.

There is no way to retrieve the full credit card number from a vaulted transaction. For this case, you would want to prompt the customer for their full card details upon setting up a billing agreement.